# Find position of parent node using xpath

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, parent

How to get the position of parent node in the complete document using xpath?

say I have the following xml:

```
<catalog>
  <cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>CBS Records</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1988</year>
  </cd>
</catalog>
```

and I have a XSLT to convert it into HTML, which is as follows (only snippet):

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
  <body>  
  <xsl:apply-templates/>  
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cd">
  <p>
    <xsl:number format="1. "/><br/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="title"/>  
    <xsl:apply-templates select="artist"/>
  </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="title">
  <xsl:number format="1" select="????" /><br/>
  Title: <span style="color:#ff0000">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/></span>
  <br />
</xsl:template>
```

What should I write at the place of ???? to get position of the parent cd tag in the document.
I have tried many expressions but nothing seems to be working. May be I am doing it altogether wrong.

1. `<xsl:number format="1" select="catalog/cd/preceding-sibling::..[position()]" />`
2. `<xsl:number format="1" select="./parent::..[position()]" /><br/>`
3. `<xsl:value-of select="count(cd/preceding-sibling::*)+1" /><br/>`

I am interpreting 2nd as select current node's parent axis and then tell the position of parent of the current node. Why is it not working? What is the correct way to do this.

FYI: I expect the code to print the position of parent cd tag of the current title tag uder processing.

Please can someone tell me  how to do this.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
count(../preceding-sibling::cd) + 1
```

You can [run it here](http://www.xmlplayground.com/sJjh7F) (note I removed the other number you were outputting, just for clarity).

You were on the right lines, but remember that predicates are used only to filter nodes, not to return information. So:

```
../*[position()]
```

...effectively says "find me the parent that has a position". It returns the node, not the position itself. The predicate is just a filter.

In any case there are pitfalls with using `position()`, and it can be used to return the position of the current, context node **only** - not another node.

Comment: Thanks a ton man, now it was silly of me not to try that. Thanks again :)

Comment: Just one more thing can you please explain the expression "count(../preceding-sibling::cd) + 1" as you did for "position()". I used your solution and it worked great but i am not able to understand why not "count(cd/preceding-sibling::..)+1"

Comment: Remember XSLT templates operate from the perspective of the current context node. In the template concerned, the context node is the title. Therefore, `count(cd...)` will not find any nodes because there are no child nodes of `title` called `cd` (indeed, `title` has no child nodes of any name). `cd` is the parent of `title`, not its child, hence we have to go up a level.

Comment: If you want to have the position independent of the type: "count(../preceding-sibling::*) + 1"

Answer (score 4):

Utkanos's answer works fine but my experience is that, when the xml document is large, this could lead to performance issues.

In this scenario you could simply pass the position of the parent in a param.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
  <body>  
  <xsl:apply-templates/>  
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cd">
  <p>
    <xsl:number format="1. "/><br/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="title">  
        <xsl:with-param name="parent_position" select="position()"/> <!-- Send here -->
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="artist"/>
  </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="title">
  <xsl:param name="parent_position"/> <!-- Receive here -->
  <xsl:number format="1" select="$parent_position"/><br/>
  Title: <span style="color:#ff0000">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/></span>
  <br />
</xsl:template>
```

result:

```
<html xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><body>
  <p>1. <br>1<br>
  Title: <span style="color:#ff0000">Empire Burlesque</span><br>Bob Dylan</p>
  <p>2. <br>1<br>
  Title: <span style="color:#ff0000">Hide your heart</span><br>Bonnie Tyler</p>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>   <xsl:number format="1" select="????" />
> ```
>
> What should I write at the place of ???? to get position of the parent
>   cd tag in the document.

**First of all, the above XSLT instruction is syntactically illegal -- the [`<xsl:number>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#number) instruction doesn't (cannot) have a `select` attribute**.

**Use**:

```
   <xsl:number format="1" count="cd" />
```

Comment: So it can be done using xsl:number as well. Thanks for the info. can you give some more info on how this works.

Comment: @Harshdeep: You can best learn "how this works" by clicking on the link (yes, the blue-color of `<xsl:number>` in the answer means this is a clickable link). To see the results of using this instruction, copy and paste it into your code.

Comment: I did click the link before asking you but w3 documentation is so bulky that I don't find it very 'readable'. But will look into it now for better understanding.

Comment: @Harshdeep: You can also read one of Michael Kay's XSLT books, where the style is more human.